# LaTeX package to help diagram translation of one language to another

Tags: languages, linguistics

I am learning Turkish and wanted to work on translating some Turkish text to English with the help of TeX. I think it would be better suited for the job. Wondering if a package exists to help with what I want or if there was something close.

Ideally, I would like a package that could render the following as the end result:

```
  home     to go 
  Eve    gidiyorum 
    -      -`----' 
    |      |  | 
    |      |  `- present progressive tense (first person - singular) 
    |      `- git->gid (t->d) sound change ending 
    `- dative case ending for gitmek 

  I want to go home
```

Second example:

```
   home     to go 
  Eveniz  gidiyoruz 
    -`-'    -`----' 
    | |     |  | 
    | |     |  `- present progressive tense (first person - plural) 
    | |     `- git->gid (t->d) sound change ending 
    | `- possessive suffix (second person - plural) 
    `- dative case ending for gitmek 

We are going to your home
```

Third example:

```
German  class  to buy; to get;    to continue 
               to take, receive 
Almanca dersi       almaya       devam ediyorum 
            -         `--'              -`----' 
            |          |                |  | 
            |          |                |  `- present progressive 
            |          |                |     tense (first person - 
            |          |                |     singular) 
            |          |                `- devam et->devam ed (t->d) 
            |          |                   sound change ending 
            |          `- verbal noun -mA, dative for devam etmek 
            `- accusative case ending for almak 

   I want to continue taking German class
```

The "-" and "`--'" are horizontal curly braces.

Comment: Crosspost to comp.text.tex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Right now, what your are asking for is pretty specific. Maybe more visual help would be useful, a screenshot or something similar. That way, you can show exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer uses nested stacks to achieve the result.  In addition to the `\Longstack` macro of the `stackengine` package, which I use to set the top-most word stacks, I introduce one additional macro.

That macro is `\notate{embraced letters}{lines to drop}{notation}`.  In this syntax, "notation" is a single line, though a `\parbox[t]` can overcome that.  The "lines to drop" must be counted/figured by the user, so as to make all the notations fit.  I currently use a leading `\unskip` and trailing `\ignorespaces` to avoid having to remember trailing all lines with `%` marks, but if those later prove problematic, they can be removed from the macro definition.

Interesting quirks that needed resolution.  I couldn't use `\upbracefill` for underbracing, because it has a minimum width which is larger than a single letter, and the OP clearly had cases where a single letter needed underbracing.  So I used my `scalerel` package to stretchhh a `\{` to the proper height and rotate it sideways, converting that height into a width.

Also, I don't have any `tikz` tricks up my sleeve for making an elbow turn in the notation arrow, so I just used a kerned `\hookrightarrow` to achieve something that visually works (I hope).

EDIT. Legibility could possibly be enhanced by setting the notation in a smaller size.  For example, here in `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip \baselineskip
\def\myupbracefill#1{\rotatebox{90}{\stretchto{\{}{#1}}}
\def\rlwd{.5pt}
\newcommand\notate[3]{%
  \unskip\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[-6pt]{%
    \def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[-1.5pt]{%
      \stackunder[-2pt]{\strut #1}{\myupbracefill{\wd0}}}{%
    \rule{\rlwd}{#2\baselineskip}}}{%
  \strut\kern7pt$\hookrightarrow$\rlap{ \footnotesize#3}}\ignorespaces%
}
\begin{document}
\hrulefill

  \Longstack{home\\Ev
   \notate{e}{4}{dative case ending for gitmek}
  }
~~\Longstack{to go\\gi
   \notate{d}{3}{git$\rightarrow$gid (t$\rightarrow$d) sound change ending}
   \notate{iyorum}{2}{present progressive tense (first person - singular)}
  }

I want to go home \par\hrulefill

  \Longstack{German\\ \\Almanca}
~~\Longstack{class\\ \\ders
   \notate{i}{8}{accusative case ending for almak}}
~~\Longstack{to buy; to get;\\to take; receive\\al
   \notate{maya}{7}{verbal noun -mA, dative for devam etmek}}
~~\Longstack{to continue\\ \\devam e
   \notate{d}{5}{%
     \parbox[t]{2in}{devam et$\rightarrow$devam ed (t$\rightarrow$d)\\
                     sound change ending}
   }
   \notate{iyorum}{2}{%
     \parbox[t]{2in}{present progressive\\
                     tense (first person -\\
                     singular)}
   }
  }

I want to continue taking German class \par\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3461326 I cleaned up the answer a bit.  Please see revision.