# Undersetting an arrow beneath an equation

Tags: equations, arrows

I'm looking to add an arrow underneath an equals sign to explain the step that has been taken. See below:

[image: example]

To achieve the arrow style that I like to use, I used `\drsh` from `mathabx`.

I tried using `\underset` to set this under the equals sign, but could not achieve the result I was looking for.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
  \newlength\widest 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\implies  \frac{d}{dt} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\psi (x, t)|^2 \, dx 
= \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \left[ \psi^* \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi - \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi^* \right) \psi \right] \bigg|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 
{\underset{\qquad\text{\makebox[0pt]{{\huge$\drsh$} Testing}}}{=}} 0
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: attempt]

If at all possible, I would also like to be able to draw something like the following:

[image: another_example]

I have read things about TikZ being very good for this sort of thing, but I have never used it before. If you think this is the right way to go, could you please offer me a push in the right direction?

I believe it's also worth mentioning that I have been using these `\drsh` arrows in text as well, for example something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
  \newlength\widest 
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text
\settowidth\widest{{\huge$\drsh$}}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+\labelsep\relax,labelindent=0pt,
labelwidth=\widest]
\item[{\huge$\drsh$}] Some more text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Adapting my answer at [LaTeX package to help diagram translation of one language to another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167659/latex-package-to-help-diagram-translation-of-one-language-to-another/167695#167695), I provide a first cut.

The syntax is

`\notate[B<race>]{<referenced math>}{<dropline length in \baselineskips>}{<math notation>}`

The `<math notation>` can be given as a `\parbox`, if longer text is needed (shown in first example below).

EDITED to allow multiple uses of `\notate` in a single equation, with and without underbrace as specified.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\parskip \baselineskip
\def\svmybf#1{\rotatebox{90}{\stretchto{\{}{#1}}}
\def\svnobf#1{}
\def\rlwd{.5pt}
\newcommand\notate[4][B]{%
  \if B#1\let\myupbracefill\svmybf\else\let\myupbracefill\svnobf\fi%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[-6pt]{%
    \def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[-1.5pt]{%
      \stackunder[2pt]{\strut $\displaystyle#2$}{\myupbracefill{\wd0}}}{%
    \rule{\rlwd}{#3\baselineskip}}}{%
  \strut\kern9pt$\rightarrow$\smash{\rlap{$~\displaystyle#4$}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\implies  \frac{d}{dt} \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\psi (x, t)|^2 \, dx 
= \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \left[ \psi^* \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi - \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi^* \right) \psi \right] \bigg|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 
\notate[X]{{}={}}{2}{\parbox[t]{1in}{Here, $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ are the
  blah-blah variables.}} 0
  \hspace{5ex}
\end{equation*}
\bigskip
\[
y = \psi^*
  \notate{\frac{d\psi}{dt}}{4}{
    \frac{d\psi}{dt} = \frac{ih}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\psi 
      - \frac{i}{h} V\psi
  }
  + \notate{\frac{d\psi^*}{dt}}{1}{
    \frac{d\psi*}{dt} = -\frac{ih}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\psi^* 
      + \frac{i}{h} V\psi
  } 
  \psi
  \hspace{14ex}
\]

\[ S = \int \notate[X]{L}{2.5}{\text{1st: No brace, as expected}} 
  \notate{dV}{1}{\text{2nd: Should have the brace!}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this solution avoids the overlapping lines shown by the OP for a multi-part comment.

Since the math notation is `\rlap`ped, the overall effect can be shifted left as needed by adding an `\hspace{<length>}` to the end of the equation.

Because the math notation is `\smash`ed, some extra skip may be needed for multi-line notations.

Comment: Thanks! I simply used `\parbox` for multi-line comments

Comment: I fail to use the command `\notate` for the equation that contains `&` in the `align` environment.

Comment: @raf. It seems to work for me with `align`.  However, you have to manually account for the width of the notation (in my examples above, it is the `\hspace` that does this).

Comment: Regarding the `&` in `align` environment, I meant having a problem while using this way: `\begin{align}
    E &= h\nu \\
    \notate{E &= mc^2}{1}{<>}
\end{align}`.

Comment: @raf Aha.  There is no way that `\notate` can work *across* a `&` boundary of `align`.

Comment: When I use your `notate` command twice in the same equation in this way: `\[ S = \int \notate[X]{L}{2}{\text{1st: No brace, as expected}} \notate{dV}{1}{\text{2nd: Should have the brace!}} \]`. Unexpectedly, both arrows appear without the brace. Can you please check why is it happening? I want to display 1st one without the brace and 2nd one with the brace.

Comment: @raf Please see my edit for the fix.

Comment: Thank you so much. Nowadays, it is one of my most frequently used commands. That's why it made me ask a follow-up [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683524/114006) to customize it with some more features. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library; the basic idea is to place some marks that will be later used to draw the braces with the arrows and place the explanatory texts:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\implies  
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lvert\psi (x, t)\rvert^2 \, dx 
= \frac{i\hbar}{2m} \Bigl[ \psi^* \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi 
  - \Bigl( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi^* \Bigr) \psi \Bigr] 
  \biggm|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\tikzmark{zero}= 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,>=latex]
  ([shift={(8pt,-2pt)}]pic cs:zero) |- 
  ++(10pt,-20pt) 
  node[right,text width=3cm] 
    {And here we add the explanation for this equality
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\[
y = \psi^* \frac{d\psi}{\tikzmark{starta}dt\tikzmark{enda}} + \frac{d\psi^*}{\tikzmark{startb}dt\tikzmark{endb}}\psi
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]
  ([xshift=-3pt]pic cs:starta) -- node (aux) {} ([xshift=3pt]pic cs:enda);
\draw[->,>=latex]
  (aux) |-
  ++(10pt,-50pt) 
  node[right] 
    {$\displaystyle\frac{d\psi}{dt} = \frac{ih}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\psi 
      - \frac{i}{h} V\psi$%
    };  
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]
  ([xshift=-3pt]pic cs:startb) -- node (auxi) {} ([xshift=3pt]pic cs:endb);
\draw[->,>=latex]
  (auxi) |-
  ++(10pt,-20pt) 
  node[right] 
    {$\displaystyle\frac{d\psi*}{dt} = -\frac{ih}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\psi^* 
      + \frac{i}{h} V\psi$%
    };  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]