# Multiple pictures in a slide with lines to a specific place

Tags: beamer

I want to create the following image from a PowerPoint presentation into a `beamer` slide

[image]

My problem is that I want every box to be linked with a line to the central text on a specific point and that is what I don't know how to do. Is there an environment or a way to do it somehow easily?

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried the _tikzmark_ library of **[TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de)**? For instane [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281121/arrows-from-equation-causing-equation-to-look-untidy/281122#281122) you can see how it's used, but there are many more questionss using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is draw picture:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}

\newcommand{\firmlist}{\setlength\itemsep{0pt}}
    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         shorten < = 1mm,
     node distance = 3mm and 0mm, %on grid,
      start chain = 1 going below,
      start chain = 2 going right,
 box/.style = {draw=blue!60!black, fill=blue!40, inner sep=1mm,
               text width=37mm, align=left, on chain=1},
type/.style = {font=\bfseries\large,
               text depth=0.5ex, text height=2ex,
               inner xsep=0mm, inner ysep=0.5mm, outer sep=0mm, on chain=2},
                        ]
\node (A) [box] {Arrival proces
            \begin{itemize}\firmlist
            \item M: Markovian
            \item D: Determistic
            \item Er: Erlang
            \item G: General
            \end{itemize}};
\node (B) [box] {Number of servers\\  $m=1,2,\dots$};
\node (C) [box] {Storage capacity\\ $>K=1,2,\dots$\\(at $K=\infty$ is omitted)};
%
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={type}]
\node (T1) [above right=0mm and 3mm of B]   {A};
\node (T2) {/};
\node (T3) {B};
\node (T4) {m};
\node (T5) {K};
\node (T6) {/};
\node (T7) {N};
\end{scope}
\node (D) [box, below right= 3mm of A.north -| T7.east]
            {Arrival proces
            \begin{itemize}\firmlist
            \item M: Markovian
            \item D: Determistic
            \item Er: Erlang
            \item G: General
            \end{itemize}};
\node (E) [box] {Number of custumers\\ $N=1,2,\dots$\\
                (for closed networks, otherwise is omitted)};
%
\draw (A) -| (T1);
\draw (B) -| (T3);
\draw (C) -| (T5);
\draw (D) -| (T3);
\draw (E) -| (T7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so so very much!! :) You tought me how to do something I had never done before and I am sure I will use this code for many more slides I have to create! Thanks again for taking the time! :)

Comment: @user2372494, I'm glad to help you! Since you accept answer, you can up-vote it too :-). Happy TeXing!

Comment: I am upvoting it so hard but I doesn't work with no reputation! Once I have 15 I'll upvote it for sure! :)