# Overset alignment above text and inserted whitespace

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, overset

I'd like to insert an annotation above equations without breaking the spacing of that equation. The annotation should be aligned to the left, and begin with an arrow that points down on the first symbol.

### Code

```
\newcommand{\hookdownleft}{\rotatebox[origin=b]{90}{$\Lsh$}}
\begin{dfn}
$\overset{\hookdownleft \text{family of sets from } \Omega \: 
\rightarrow \: \text{one set from } \Omega}{op} \in \mathcal{O} = 
\set{\text{set operations}}}$
\end{dfn}
```

### Output

[image: current]

### Desired

[image: desired]

Comment: Welcome t tex.sx.  You might try using `\mathrlap` (provided by the `mathtools` package) to make LaTeX think the notation has no width.

Comment: `\mathrlap{overset{...}{..}}` doesn't do any good. The annotation and the rest of the definition get moved to the beginning of the line, but the symbol above the annotation (`op`) stays in place, creating overlapping text.

Comment: The `\mathrlap` should go *inside* the `\overset`: `\overset{\mathrlap{\hookdownleft \text{family of sets ...}}}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by Barbara Beeton, the simplest solution uses `\mathrlap`from `mathtools` *inside* the first argument of \overset. I added a `\mathstrut` to the second argument, to ensure a correct vertical spacing between the overset thing and the main line of equation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set}\{\}
\usepackage{rotating, bigstrut}
    \newcommand{\hookdownleft}{\rotatebox[origin=b]{90}{$\Lsh$}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{dfn}
$\overset{\mathrlap{\hookdownleft \text{family of sets from } \Omega \:
\rightarrow \: \text{one set from } \Omega}}{op\mathstrut} \in \mathcal{O} =
\set{\text{set operations}}$
\end{dfn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation. I'm guessing I should have provided a more complete code example.