# Custom command to notate specific terms in equation with arrows

Tags: math-mode, equations, arrows

Currently, I am using the custom command `notate` from this [TeX SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263491/114006).
The syntax of this command is:

`\notate[B<race>]{<referenced math>}{<dropline length in \baselineskips>}{<math notation>}`

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}

% \parskip \baselineskip  % it's creating a problem with my theorem environment designs
\def\svmybf#1{\rotatebox{90}{\stretchto{\{}{#1}}}
\def\svnobf#1{}
\def\rlwd{.5pt}
\newcommand\notate[4][B]{%
  \if B#1\let\myupbracefill\svmybf\else\let\myupbracefill\svnobf\fi%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[-6pt]{%
    \def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[-1.5pt]{%
      \stackunder[2pt]{\strut $\displaystyle#2$}{\myupbracefill{\wd0}}}{%
    \rule{\rlwd}{#3\baselineskip}}}{%
  \strut\kern9pt$\rightarrow$\smash{\rlap{$~\displaystyle#4$}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
   S = \int \sqrt{\notate[X]{F}{1}{\text{$F$ is functional}}[x^a(\tau)]} d\tau
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

But my desired output is the following:

[image]

What do I need to change in the `notate` command to get the desired output?

Another feature I like to have in the command is regarding the placement of the arrowhead as an optional argument such that it can be placed in the direction of the `<math notation>` or/and the `<referenced math>` according to user choice. By default, it should be directed to the `<math notation>`. My desired syntax for the command:

`\notate[<Brace>, <arrowhead>]{<referenced math>}{<dropline length in \baselineskips>}{<math notation>}`

where the default choice would be such that the brace is at to the `<referenced math>` and the arrowhead is directed to the `<math notation>`.
For example:

1. The following two should generate the same output and `[B,A]` considered as the default choice for the optional argument:

```
\notate[B,A]{<referenced math>}{1}{<math notation>}
\notate{<referenced math>}{1}{<math notation>}
```

2. To remove the brace and keep the arrowhead at the `<math notation>` only:

```
\notate[X,A]{<referenced math>}{1}{<math notation>}
```

3. To switch the positions of the brace and arrowhead (the arrowhead is at the `<referance math>` and the brace is at the opposite end):

```
\notate[A,B]{<referenced math>}{1}{<math notation>}
```

4. To keep the arrowheads at both ends:

```
\notate[A,A]{<referenced math>}{1}{<math notation>}
```

5. To keep both ends blank (no brace, no arrowhead):

```
\notate[X,X]{<referenced math>}{1}{<math notation>}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use `annotate-equations` package. The only difference with the default output of the package is the direction of the arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}
\usepackage{derivative}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\eqnannotationfont}{\footnotesize}
\begin{equation*}
S = \int \sqrt{\tikzmarknode{f}{F}[x^a(\tau)]}\odif{\tau}
\end{equation*}
\annotate[yshift=-1em]{below}{f}{$F$ is functional}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Something not related: According to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14822/140456) differentials should be upright, not italicized. I change the differential using `derivative` package.

Of course, another alternative could be `tikzmark` package. In any case, as a mere user, I believe it is better to use a package that is shipped with a documentation rather than code that can be not fully understood.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the `derivative` package too.

Answer (score 2):

As to the direct question on how to achieve the desired result for the presented equation, one need only `\smash` the `\notate` command.

EDITED to show a little more flexibility in the arrowhead choice.  As before, `B` optional argument provides a upbrace on the referenced math.  However, a `U` provides an `\uparrow` instead of a simple line-end.

Similar logic could be employed for rendering the `\rightarrow` or not, depending on the value of the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}

% \parskip \baselineskip
\def\myupbracefill#1{\rotatebox{90}{\stretchto{\{}{#1}}}
\def\rlwd{.4pt}
\newcommand\notate[4][B]{%
  \if B#1\else\def\myupbracefill##1{}%
    \if U#1\def\myuparrow{$\uparrow$}\else\def\myuparrow{}\fi\fi%
  \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[-6pt]{%
    \def\stackalignment{c}\stackunder[-1.5pt]{%
      \stackunder[2pt]{\strut $\displaystyle#2$}{\myupbracefill{\wd0}}}{%
    \stackunder[-.2pt]{\myuparrow}{\rule{\rlwd}{#3\baselineskip}}}}{%
  \strut\kern9pt$\rightarrow$\smash{\rlap{$~\displaystyle#4$}}}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
   S = \int \sqrt{
  \smash{\notate[X]{F}{1}{\text{$F$ is functional}}}
  [x^a(\tau)]} d\tau
\end{equation*}
\bigskip
\begin{equation*}
   S = \int \sqrt{
  \smash{\notate[U]{F}{.2}{\text{$F$ is functional}}}
  [x^a(\tau)]} d\tau
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you and I am looking forward to your updates about the features.

Comment: Note, @raf that some `\vspace` may be needed before whatever text follows after this equation, because of the `\smash`

Comment: Have you thought about the other feature requests later?

Comment: @raf please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't understand how to control the arrowhead and brace properly. So, I have updated the question to express my feature request more clearly (with 5 cases) to you. Also, your updated answer is giving an error `Undefined control sequence` when no optional argument is used. For example, it gives an error for the line: `S = \int \sqrt{  \smash{\notate{F}{1}{\text{$F$ is functional}}}  [x^a(\tau)]} d\tau`. Kindly have a look when you get time.