# How to create an overhanging label for parts of a sentence?

Tags: labels

Reference image attached.[image]
I also want to be able to change the colour of there arrows and label text, etc.

Comment: Does this help?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183032/sentence-diagramming

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167659/latex-package-to-help-diagram-translation-of-one-language-to-another and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT:** A newer version with more functionality is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430092/120953) as an answer to a follow up question.

---

I have written a command `\mylabel` which takes the inline text as first mandatory argument and the label text as second mandatory argument.
You can customize the appearance globally (for the current group) with `\setmylabel` or locally (for this one usage) with an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


% --------------- def options ---------------

\pgfqkeys{/mylabel}{%
    % geometry
    shift x/.initial = 1.5em,
    shift y/.initial = .2em,
    slope width/.initial = .3em,
    text xsep/.initial  = .1em,
    text ysep/.initial  = .1em,
    label xsep/.initial = .3333em,
    label ysep/.initial = .3333em,
    %
    % colors
    line color/.initial  = black,
    text color/.initial  = black,
    label color/.initial = black,
    color/.style = {line color=#1, label color=#1},
    %
    % label positions
    /mylabel/pos/.is choice,
    /mylabel/pos/above/.style = {pos=above right},
    /mylabel/pos/below/.style = {pos=below right},
    /mylabel/pos/below right/.style = {%
        _anchor label  = north west,
        _direction     = below,
        _line pos      = south,
    },
    /mylabel/pos/above right/.style = {%
        _anchor label  = south west,
        _direction     = above,
        _line pos      = north,
    },
    %
    % internal
    _anchor label/.initial,
    _direction/.initial,
    _line pos/.initial,
    %
    % struts
    inline strut/.initial=\vphantom{Ap},
    label strut/.initial=\strut,
}

\newcommand{\setmylabel}[1]{%
    \pgfqkeys{/mylabel}{#1}%
}


% --------------- init options ---------------

\setmylabel{%
    pos = below,
}


% --------------- \mylabel command ---------------

\newcommand{\mylabel}[3][]{% [#1: options], #2: inline text, #3: label text
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(inline.base)]
        % process options
        \setmylabel{#1}

        % draw text
        \node[%
            inner ysep = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/text xsep},
            inner xsep = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/text ysep},
            text = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/text color},
        ] (inline) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/inline strut}#2};
        \node (label) [
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/_direction} = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/shift y} of inline,
            xshift = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/shift x},
            anchor = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/_anchor label},
            inner xsep = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/label xsep},
            inner ysep = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/label ysep},
            text = \pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/label color},
        ] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/label strut}#3};

        % draw lines
        \draw[draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/line color}]
            (inline.\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/_line pos} west) -- (inline.\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/_line pos} east)
            (inline.\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/_line pos}) -- ([xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/slope width}] inline.\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/_line pos} |- label) -- (label);
        ;

        % set bounding box
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \useasboundingbox 
            (inline.south west) rectangle (inline.north east)
            (inline |- label.south) rectangle (inline |- label.north)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


% --------------- test document ---------------

\setmylabel{%
    line color  = orange,
    text color  = blue,
    label color = green,
}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    text \mylabel[pos=above]{part}{label~1} of a \mylabel{sentence}{label~2}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

I recommend to put def options, init options and \mylabel command in a separate file *mylabel.tex* in a subdirectory *preamble* and include it with `\input{preamble/mylabel}`.

[image]

---

EDIT: For even more customization you can add another pgfkey

```
line/.initial =,
```

and replace the first line of the code "draw lines" with

```
\pgfkeys{/mylabel/line/.get=\tmpLineStyle}%
\expandafter \draw \expandafter [\tmpLineStyle, draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/mylabel/line color}]
```

then you have another option called `line` to which you can pass values like `dotted`, `dashed`, `double`, `thick`, `thin`, `line width=2pt` and so on (see [Ti*k*Z documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) section 15.3 *Drawing a Path*).
You can combine several values by joining them with a comma. If the value contains a comma or an equals sign it must be surrounded by braces.

For example:

```
line = {thick, dashed},
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to modify your solution in a way that doesn't affect the space between lines? Obv in this case labels overlap with text but it's not a problem since I want to use it in drafts. If you want I can ask a separate question for this.

Comment: I added a separate question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429824/how-to-create-an-overhanging-label-for-parts-of-a-sentence-further-improvement)

Comment: @giusva yes, that's easy. Just remove `(inline |- label.south) rectangle (inline |- label.north)` from `\useasboundingbox`. (Depending on the `text ysep` option it may still add a little space, though.)

Comment: Thanks, can you please check my question. I've added just a **small** request: how to position the labels with a fixed offset wrt the page instead of a fixed offset wrt the part of the sentence one is referring to.

Comment: @giusva yes, I have read the question and I have started working on an update. I hope I can finish it tomorrow.